# JavaScript Syntax Check

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

Folks,

Quick question; could someone check if this syntax is proper? I'm getting errors through firefox 1.7.3 and ie8 regarding this and can't get it for the life of me.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: Errors or warnings? There's a number of minor potential issues (for example type missing in the script tag)

Comment: If you're getting errors, it's not proper syntax. You should always show what the error message says.

Comment: It's an error. So...the page sits in a .dwt Dreamweaver template file, and it's part of the footer. When removed from the template the syntax error goes away.

Comment: Webpage error details

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://site/js/selectivizr-and-extra-selectors.min.js


Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://site/phone/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js


Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://site/phone/js/respond.min.js

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape `/` in your `document.write` for starters (so `\` is failing because it doesn't recognize `\/` as a valid escape sequence).

However, when you remove that `</script>` would appear which would make the XML parser fail. (`<script>...</script>` is what the parser is looking for; it doesn't care if it's within (what we see as) a string) So, concatenation is introduced: `</scr'+'ipt>`.

Altogether, we have:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>');</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

When the parser encounters the first `</script>` it ends the script tag. so this fix should work:

```
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></sc'+'ript>');
</script>
```

Comment: May be helpful to explain why `</script>` should be broken up. Also, it only needs to be broken up because typically the `/` isn't escaped as it is in the OPs version.

Comment: do the `/`s in the src attribute need to be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a different approach for dynamic script loading.  For example:

```
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'helper.js';
//append script somewhere on the dom
```

Comment: IIRC this will load the script asynchronously, so that has to be kept in mind.

Comment: Note that `type` is not needed in HTML5.